# SQLite model to JAVA classes

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite db and I have to make it work with an Android application.

So my question is:
Is there any way to generate JAVA classes automatically from an SQLite db model?
This db has several tables and I would like to get a JAVA class for each table to handle easily my datas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no official way to do this right now - at least not from Google. You can still feed your db schema to some 3rd party app that can generate these classes for you. Or you could even write a script/app for this.